# Full width Youtube embed hero background video

Tags: html, css, youtube, responsive

I'm looking for a HTML & CSS way to display this embed video as a 75vh height hero background.

For now, the iFrame keep his `width: 100%` and his `height: 75vh` but the images in itselves aren't covering the whole header width.

**Actually, I need it to behave like a** `background-size: cover` **property**.

Here is a quick attached jsfiddle to illustrate this issue, best way to see it is in a new tab.

> https://jsfiddle.net/wollsale/9yrvLy72/

PS : I know there is a loads of articles talking about that kind of problem, but I didn't found a solution that works for me.

```css
body {
  background: #aaa;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 2000px;
}

body {
  background: #aaa;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 2000px;
}

header {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 75vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.video__wrapper {
  position: relative; padding-bottom: 53.25%; /* 16:9 */  padding-top: 25px;
}

.video__inner {
   position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w7Ap0k7qp2k?autoplay=1&loop=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&controls=0&autohide=1" frameborder="0" class="video__inner"></iframe>
  </header>
  
  <main></main>
  
</body>
```

---

**EDIT**

This article explain how to use HTML & CSS only to kind of "crop" a video in order to make it covering to whole viewport.

> https://fvsch.com/code/video-background/

See it in action with this great codepen

> https://codepen.io/cvn/pen/WbXEoX?q=youtube+object+fit&limit=all&type=type-pens

Comment: here is codepen link which might help you https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/PZyMrd?editors=0100

Comment: I already try this solution, but it works for a full page backgroud video. I need it for a hero background vid, the iFrame cover full widh & height but the image is rounded by black border. It's more a `background-size: contain` than a `background-size: cover` behaviour :)

Comment: Actually I just found this post by accident : 
> https://codepen.io/cvn/pen/WbXEoX?q=youtube+object+fit&limit=all&type=type-pens
And it works like a charm. I don't even know how, but I'll take a quick moment to understand all of this logic and will post an answer to my own question!

Comment: if it's what you were looking for then it's great ;)

Answer (score 0):

This article explain how to use HTML & CSS only to kind of "crop" a video in order to make it covering to whole viewport.

> https://fvsch.com/code/video-background/

See it in action with this great `codepen`

> https://codepen.io/cvn/pen/WbXEoX?q=youtube+object+fit&limit=all&type=type-pens